# How to disable chunking in cxf-jaxrs client

Tags: http, cxf, jax-rs

I need to contact a proprietary http service, not supporting chunks.
I started using  as [documented here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html) so i create the client this way:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rs");
```

The problem is how to configure the client, how to disable chunking. The way [documented here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-Usingjavacode) doesn't work for me (wrong classes).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather that using jaxrs standard Client you can use  `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient` part of `cxf-rt-rs-client` dependency.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/rs");
WebClient.getConfig(client).getHttpConduit().getClient().setAllowChunking(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to continue to use the `ClientBuilder` etc, you can do this instead:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target("https://www.example.com/");
target.request(); /* Must call this first to initialise the client in the target */
WebClient.getConfig(target).getHttpConduit().getClient().setAllowChunking(false);
```