# What does Wiresharks http chunked response represent

Tags: tomcat8, wireshark

I'm having an issue posting to a restfull api.

Done via Postman, it works fine.

Done via our application which uses Tomcat 8.5 it fails.
I'm getting no useful error messages from server (Request is getting there though.)
When I send a smaller json payload it works via application.

I decided to use wireshark to compare the requests.
The only differnece I can see is that postman is setting transfer-encoding to gzip (Postman works).
The request appears to be chunked when done via our application.

Number 59432 is what I have expanded in image below, it is the initial request to the server.

Does the 'http chunked response' mean that the request I made was split up into chunks before sending?
Or is it saying that the response from 59435 is chunked?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that anwser is yes, the 'HTTP chunked response' in the request is the request broken up into chunks.

I was able to disable chunking in Jax-RS and the request now responds with 200ok, next issue is to the get service provider to enable chunking support on their side.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315339/how-to-disable-chunking-in-cxf-jaxrs-client) answer showed me how to disable chunking in request for Jax-RS.